An async/parallel approach to working a (potentially) growing task queue
I have a list of items that need to be processed and I want to be able to process them in parallel for efficiency. But during the processing of one item I may discover more items that need to be added to the list to be processed.
I've looked at the multiprocessing and concurrent libraries but I couldn't find a feature of a queue of this sort that can be modified during runtime, or after it's been passed to the pool. Is there a solution that meets my desires?
Here's some code that demonstrates what I'm wanting.
i = 0
jobs_to_be_processed = [f'job{(i:=i+1)}' for _ in range(5)]

def process_job(job):
    if int(job[-1]) % 3 == 0:
        jobs_to_be_processed.append(f'new job{(i:=i+1)}')
    # do process job ...
    pass

# Add jobs to a pool that allows `jobs_to_be_processed`
# to have jobs added while processing
pool = AsyncJobPool(jobs_to_be_processed)
pool.start()
pool.join()


Not sure what is wrong about multiprocess.Queue or multiprocess.Pipe (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) ?
For problems like this i used to prepare additional managing thread which had Pipes/Queues to every worker thread, and it was able to manage the load on each worker thread.

@user3621602 are the Queues able to added to during the time that the processes are running?

IIUC you can use asyncio.Queue where you put your items to be processed, e.g.:
import asyncio


async def worker(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()

        if item == 'spawn more jobs':
            print('Spawning more jobs!')
            queue.put_nowait('other1')
            queue.put_nowait('other2')
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(f'Processed job item: {item}')

        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    # we have pool of 2 workers that work concurrently:
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(q)) for i in range(2)]

    # initially we have 4 job items (one item spawns 2 more jobs):
    for job in ['job1', 'job2', 'spawn more jobs', 'job3']:
        q.put_nowait(job)

    await q.join()

    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())

This prints:
Processed job item: job1
Spawning more jobs!
Processed job item: job2
Processed job item: job3
Processed job item: other1
Processed job item: other2

